# org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure - could not read a hi value

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I work with a `Spring MVC/ Hibernate` app and re-started it after a while again to work on. This time I get the following errors,

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: could not read a hi value - you need to populate the table: hibernate_sequence
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:787)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:765)
    at mobi.puut.database.WalletInfoDaoHibernate.create(WalletInfoDaoHibernate.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.create(Unknown Source)
    at mobi.puut.services.WalletServiceImpl.createWalletInfo(WalletServiceImpl.java:279)
    at mobi.puut.services.WalletServiceImpl.lambda$generateAddress$0(WalletServiceImpl.java:104)
    at mobi.puut.controllers.WalletManager$1.lambda$onSetupCompleted$0(WalletManager.java:105)
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.forEach(Collections.java:2062)
    at mobi.puut.controllers.WalletManager$1.onSetupCompleted(WalletManager.java:105)
    at org.bitcoinj.kits.WalletAppKit.startUp(WalletAppKit.java:325)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractIdleService$2$1.run(AbstractIdleService.java:54)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Callables$3.run(Callables.java:95)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: could not read a hi value - you need to populate the table: hibernate_sequence
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1$1.execute(TableStructure.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1$1.execute(TableStructure.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.WorkExecutor.executeReturningWork(WorkExecutor.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractReturningWork.accept(AbstractReturningWork.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.delegateWork(JdbcIsolationDelegate.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure$1.getNextValue(TableStructure.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.NoopOptimizer.generate(NoopOptimizer.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.generate(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:432)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:780)
    ... 23 more
org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableStructure: 08/15/2017 13:48:27 - could not read a hi value - you need to populate the table: hibernate_sequence
Exception in thread " STARTING" java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl@5e9059bd is closed
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.errorIfClosed(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.rollback(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.rollback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:239)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:100)
    at mobi.puut.database.WalletInfoDaoHibernate.create(WalletInfoDaoHibernate.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.create(Unknown Source)
    at mobi.puut.services.WalletServiceImpl.createWalletInfo(WalletServiceImpl.java:279)
    at mobi.puut.services.WalletServiceImpl.lambda$generateAddress$0(WalletServiceImpl.java:104)
    at mobi.puut.controllers.WalletManager$1.lambda$onSetupCompleted$0(WalletManager.java:105)
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.forEach(Collections.java:2062)
    at mobi.puut.controllers.WalletManager$1.onSetupCompleted(WalletManager.java:105)
    at org.bitcoinj.kits.WalletAppKit.startUp(WalletAppKit.java:325)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractIdleService$2$1.run(AbstractIdleService.java:54)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Callables$3.run(Callables.java:95)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have few tables in the `Database` and the `hibernate_sequence` table is provided below,

[image]

I have seen someone is suggested in the forum to fill the `hibernate_sequence` table as following and I have done this which doesn't solve it issue.

```
Insert into wallet.hibernate_sequence(next_val) values(0)
```

I use `Java annotation based` config and the database connection is provided below,

```
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

        // dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wallet?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wallet");
        dataSource.setUsername("testuser");
        dataSource.setPassword("testpassword");

        return dataSource;
    }

    Properties hibernateProperties() {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
//        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", "false");
        return properties;
    }
```

Here is the `POM` I use for the app,

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.puut.wallet</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <artifactId>BitcoinWalletApp</artifactId>
    <name>Bitcoin Wallet</name>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.bitcoinj</groupId>
        <artifactId>bitcoinj-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.14.4</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.3.10.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.security.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>

        <!--crypto-currencies dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bitcoinj</groupId>
            <artifactId>bitcoinj-core</artifactId>
            <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--spring dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--spring security dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--web API dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.glxn</groupId>
            <artifactId>qrgen</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--testing and database dependencies incl. hibernate-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Jackson dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Here is the `WalletInfo` pojo,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "wallet_info")
public class WalletInfo {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

Whats the issue here and how to solve it?

Comment: please paste your stacktrace as a code

Comment: I have posted the `error stack` as code

Comment: great, I'm trying to reproduce the error

Comment: could you tell me the driver's, the mysql's itself, the hibernate's versions?

Comment: I provided the `POM` for the project

Comment: cool, what generation type are you using for your pojos?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are not maintaining any sequence in database, then Use
 `@GeneratedValue(strategy = javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY )` 
It will automatically maintain a unique Identification for your table.

javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY

The IDENTITY option simply allows the database to generate a unique primary key for your application. No sequence or table is used to maintain the primary key information, but instead, the database will just pick an appropriate, unique number for Hibernate to assign to the primary key of the entity. With MySQL, the first lowest numbered primary key available in the table in question is chosen, although this behavior may differ from database to database.

Answer (score 2):

Just run the insert sentences as many times as there are many tables in the relevant database.

```
INSERT INTO `hibernate_sequence` (`next_val`) VALUES ('<the value bigger than max id of all the table within the relevant db>');
```

Comment: This really helps after 4 years during the time I'm considering moving into the DevOps. LOL